# error in wubi installer inside windows 8

Tags: 12.10, wubi

when I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit in both ways(from CD and internet download) through Wubi it gives me an error (`could not retrieve installation files`).

I want your help to pass this problem. If there's no other way but to install it by booting from CD, is there any way to keep my Windows?

Here's the log file:
http://pastebin.com/Pyw1ZrRh

Comment: did you downloaded 32bit version of ubuntu? if so you need to add `--32bit` argument in wubi. Second thing, is your laptop in secure boot /UEFI mode? secure boot is not compatible with wubi. More help - http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/35775 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: I am downloading the 64 bit version @Web-E

Comment: Put the log file on pastebin. I'm not going to sign up to download it.

Comment: it's on pastebin now @bcbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in the logfile. First time you ran Wubi it found an `\ubuntu` directory already present.

The second time it downloaded the preinstalled disk image `ubuntu-12.10-wubi-amd64.tar.xz`, but the download was incomplete, so extraction failed:

```
11-22 01:11 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\disks\ubuntu-12.10-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, url=http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, basename=ubuntu-12.10-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, 
                   length=562061340, text=None
11-22 02:02 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 207376145 bytes)
11-22 02:02 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
11-22 02:02 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished get_diskimage
11-22 02:02 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_diskimage...
11-22 02:02 ERROR  TaskList: Extraction failed with code: 2
```

After that you had a CD in `G:\`, but this isn't a valid image as it is failing the `md5sum` check. I noticed that the `md5sum` shows two different invalid md5sums, so I assume you have tried two different CDs (or mounted two different ISOs):

```
12-14 12:07 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
12-14 12:07 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal Quetzal" - Release amd64 (20121017.5)
12-14 12:07 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '12.10', 'build': '20121017.5', 'codename': 'Quantal Quetzal', 'arch': 'amd64'}
12-14 12:07 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: G:\
12-14 12:07 INFO   root: Running the CD menu...
...
12-14 11:48 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
12-14 11:48 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
12-14 11:48 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
12-14 11:49 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
12-14 11:49 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (7ad57cadae955bd04019389d4b9c1dcb != 4d30a270cc24c85b33daa9d82d95b04d)
None
12-14 11:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
12-14 11:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
12-14 11:49 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
12-14 11:49 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
```

The correct `md5sum` for that ISO is:

```
7ad57cadae955bd04019389d4b9c1dcb *ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

So the solution is to download the ISO again and if Wubi fails, check the log file to see if the `md5sum` is good.

A couple of points for installing... if you want to install with Wubi (inside Windows) then you should place the downloaded ISO in the same directory as `wubi.exe` before running Wubi. If you burn it to a CD or mount it as a CD, then it will offer the "CD menu" which doesn't include the "Install inside Windows" option. (Or you can run it off the CD with the `--force-wubi` option).

Also, for computers purchased with preinstalled Windows 8, Wubi doesn't currently work due to lack of support for GPT disks - I think it's okay in your case as it says you have a 32 bit version of Windows 8).

Finally, you can install Ubuntu by booting from the CD AND keep Windows. The Ubuntu installer (`ubiquity`) will offer to split Windows and create a side-by-side dual boot install (except in certain cases where you have used the max partitions). This is the best solution if you want a permanent Ubuntu install (Wubi is more to try out Ubuntu).