# Ubuntu Installation Error : Extraction failed with code 2

Tags: wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine. These are the steps I followed:

Create a partition using the disk manager.

Download Wubi.

Run Wubi as administrator.

I get the following error message after the download is complete:

Extraction failed with code: 2 For more information, please see the log file: C:\Windows\Temp\wubi-12.04-rev266.log

These are the lines in the log file where the error messages were seen.

```
  12-31 20:12 ERROR TaskList: Non fatal error [Errno 14] HTTP –  New_account 8 mins ago    

    Error 404: Not Found in task download Traceback (most recent call last): File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in call File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 450, in extract_diskimage Exception: Extraction failed with code: 2 12-31 21:58 DEBUG TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist 12-31 21:58 DEBUG TaskList: # Finished tasklist 12-31 21:58 ERROR root: Extraction failed with code: 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 450, in extract_diskimage
Exception: Extraction failed with code: 2
12-31 21:58 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
12-31 21:58 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
12-31 21:58 ERROR  root: Extraction failed with code: 2

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong.
```

Comment: Version 266 is really really old. Wubi doesn't like old versions (unless you can install offline). So, that's the main problem. Extraction failure is generally the older disk image being corrupt. These aren't used anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error in wubi installer inside windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/228948/error-in-wubi-installer-inside-windows-8) (the log file in this one has a number of failures and one of them is the disk extraction error)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you have quoted, I can understand that few of the files required for the Wubi installer are missing. That's the reason 404 error message pops up. Check the link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233179/why-does-wubi-fail-with-a-404-error) with similar issue which might be helpful.